# Debugging MS SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, debugging, stored-procedures

I have a problem getting Stored Procedure debugging to work in Visual Studio 2008: When I start debugging, I get these success messages in the output window, however the actual stored procedure windows does not show up.

```
Auto-attach to process '[1640] [SQL] stagsql' on machine 'stagsql' succeeded.
The thread 'stagsql [67]' (0xf80) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'stagsql [67]' (0xf80) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'stagsql [69]' (0x908) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'stagsql [69]' (0x908) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'stagsql [69]' (0x908) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'stagsql [69]' (0x908) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Running [dbo].[uspCGetXYZ] ( @nLieferantId = 161616, @nStrukturId = -1, @nPageIndex = 1, @nPageSize = 16, @sSortColumn = arLangname, @nSortAscending = 1 ).
```

Visual Studio gets into 'debug mode' but the procedure does not show up at all.

The steps I did:

- Enabled SQL debugging in the project settings
- Opened the SQL Connection in Server Explorer
- Enabled CLR/SQL debuggin on the connection
- Right-click on the procedure and selected "step into stored procedure"

Alternatively I tried to open up the procedure and set a break-point there, it didn't help.

Any ideas? As said, the connection is there but Visual Studio is not capable of opening the procedure code.

Comment: Just to check, this is a CLR stored procedure?

Comment: Has this been resolved for you?

Comment: Unfortunately now, I am now using Management Studio as debugger instead of Visual Studio :/

Comment: try a new solution just to test db debugging

Comment: also can you tell us what solution type it is so we can try replicate?

Answer (score 1):

By any chance, do you have "**Display Actual Execution Plan**" selected? I've found that debugging won't run if you have that button clicked, though I can't for the life of me figure out why that would be the case.

I haven't submitted a bug on Connect, but would be happy to upvote one if somebody knows about it.

Comment: Yes you are right. It does not . I will log it as bug and pass on the URL

Answer (score 0):

Is the solution a database solution? Did you go New->Solution->Other->Database?

Once you create a database solution then setup your connection preferences you should be able to use the server explorer to edit and step-into the stored procedure. Please verify this still causes the issue?

<strike>Are you using an express edition?</strike>

Comment: No, I use a 'normal' Solution that contains all kind of projects. Can I fix this without dropping my current solution?
I use the professional version.

Comment: Ok, try adding a new solution File->Add->New Project and then select Other Project Types->Database. That should give you the DB project in your current solution. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

See [Debugging procedure with table for sql server 2005](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2009/06/debugging-procedure-with-table-for-sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the code behind that stored procedure?  If it is saved "WITH ENCRYPTION", you may not be able to see the code and then you will need the original source code for the proc to debug it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think ou can put breakpoints into it like you could in a normal VS application.

However you can create a temp table for logging, and on each line add a new entry into that temp table.

Comment: you can debug just like you do VS application. Variables and (almost) everything else